# need to send ASCII codes over Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

Just looking for a "pre-made" device that could get ASCII codes (at the same time power up the device where the codes come from) and send the ASCII string over Bluetooth,
Technically, I want a device where I can connect standard Keyboard with a USB plug, and send the the keystrokes via bluetooth,
Just wondering if there is a device already setup to do this, no time to develop,
thanks

Comment: The search keywords you need are "Bluetooth Adapter for Keyboard" and "keyboard USB2BT adapter", besides avoiding the "DIY" acronym in the search.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to convert a USB keyboard to Bluetooth, there's a handful of options out there, like the BT-500 from handheldci.com: http://handheldsci.com/kb/

And some similar FOSS arduino version: https://github.com/juancgarcia/HID-Relay

If this is *not* what you're trying to do, you'll need to specify it a bit better. "send characters over bluetooth" is sadly not that simple, the bluetooth device has to identify as some type of device. That could be a keyboard (HID), however it could also be something like a serial port over bluetooth which something like a HM-05 implements.